# Time Series Normalization by row or by columns?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, normalization

In times series forecasting when I perform a "global training" learning from many time series simultaneously for example (SVM regression, Neural Networks and etc..).

I can normalise each time series separately to mean = 0 and std = 1.

If all data is matrix where each time series is a row it would call it "row wise" normalisation.
Or I can normalise by column, so mean and std of each feature will have 0 and 1.

$$
DATA:\\
t^1_1, t^1_2, t^1_3, t^1_4 \\
t^2_1, t^2_2, t^2_3, t^2_4 \\
t^3_1, t^3_2, t^3_3, t^3_4
$$

Just to make it more clear: upper index (new row) indicates a new time series.

$\\{\mathbb{E}}(t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4) = 0 \ \ \ \   {\bf VS} \ \ \ \ \ {\mathbb{E}}(t^1_1, t^2_1, t^3_1)=0$

What is a **better** "practice/ theory"?

Comment: Just to clarify: Each row is a time series, and each column is a time stamp, correct?

Comment: @SkanderH, Exactly.